# How to declare/set size of global array from inside a function on Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a class in my Arduino project (Arduino is basically just C++). I have a two-dimensional array called "canvas". I want to initialise the array as a variable at the start of the class. I have a function in my class which is used to pass the required canvas dimensions to the class. I want to create this array with its correct dimensions from inside this function, but then the scope of the array would not be global.

How do I do this so that I can create the array as a global class variable, but set the size of the array from inside the function?

Edit to clarify, this is what I want to happen:

```
class foo{
  int canvas[][];

  void setupCanvas(int canvasX, int canvasY){
    //I want to set the size of array "canvas" here.

    //my other option is to initialise the array "canvas" here with 
    //dimensions canvasX and canvasY.
    //Obviously that wouldn't work because I need this variable to 
    //be global.
  }
};
```

Comment: @skillz you have to provide code in the question of what you current attempt looks like

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that your problem is that you don't know how to dynamically create member arrays in a class.

```
   using namespace std;


// create your class
class MyClass {
    int m_canvasX; // we need store the array size somewhere
  public:
    int** m_canvas;
    // assign a value to your member in a method
    void setupCanvas(const int canvasX = 1, const int canvasY = 1){
      m_canvasX = canvasX;
      m_canvas = new int*[canvasX];
      for(int x = 0; x < m_canvasX; x++)
        m_canvas[x] = new int[canvasY];
      // store a value for demonstration
      m_canvas[canvasX-1][canvasY-1] = 1234;
    }

    ~MyClass(){
      for(int x = 0; x < m_canvasX; x++)
        delete[] m_canvas[x];
      delete[] m_canvas;
    }

};

int main(){

  // create an instance of your class
  int sizeX = 2;
  int sizeY = 3;
  MyClass example;
  example.setupCanvas(sizeX, sizeY);
  // print the value to proof that our code actually works
  cout << example.m_canvas[sizeX-1][sizeY-1];

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I worded my question correctly. I have edited it with an example to make my problem clearer.

Comment: @skillz21 so your question is not about the scope of canvas but on how to dynamically create an array? or what? please be more specific...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you have tried to do in your example. What I wanted to do was find a way to create variable canvas[][] that I could set to a certain size using a function that I would call straight after creating a class object. Quick clarification thought, creating canvas[][] in the constructor function means it's only in the scope of that function, correct?

Comment: @skillz21 I just did that in the constructor. you can do the same in another method. I updated my example... the example is C++ of course you won't have a main()  or cout in your arduino code.

Comment: Do you have a link to maybe a tutorial for that stuff you've done with the array? I don't really understand the "for(int x = 0; x < m_canvasX; x++)
        m_canvas[x] = new int[canvasY];" parts.

Comment: @skillz21  dynamic memory allocation. Covered by any C++ book/tutorial/course. as stated in the other answer this shoudl usually be avoided on Arduino due to limited SRAM. it will cause heap fragmentation over time.

Answer (score 0):

On Arduino, space is usually very limited, meaning that using *dynamic memory management* is usually to be avoided on a large scale since that leads to memory fragmentation over a longer run.

The following solution in itself uses no dynamic allocation:

```
constexpr int foo_max_elements = 1024;//use #define instead if compiler doesn't support constexpr
class foo{
  int canvas[foo_max_elements];
  int size_x;
  int size_y;

public:
  void foo(int canvasX, int canvasY) : size_x{canvasX}, size_y{canvasX} {
    if (size_x*size_y > foo_max_elements ) {
     //too large: handle error
    }
  }
};
```

The main drawback is that this solution always uses up the same amount of storage meaning waste for smaller objects.

Comment: waste of what? there is nothing else to use the memory

Comment: @Juraj if you make a 2x2 canvas you would only use 4 ints (unless later resized) we are still using storage for 1024 - that may or may not be an issue.